# Does using too many SemaphoreSlim(N) for managing concurrency have performance implications?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

*Problem* :
I have an HTTP client that makes request to a weather forecast restAPI . Currently there is limitation to how many concurrent calls can be made to the weather forecast API. For the current tier max concurrency limit is 60 concurrent GET calls per second. but the limit could change in the future to 100,200 or even more  .

Would using higher number of semaphores have performance implications ?

***Code***:

```
public class WeatherApiWithConcurrencyAdapter
    {
        private readonly WeatherForecastApi _weatherForecastApi;
        private const int MaxConcurrencyPerSecond = 60;
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim  ConcurrencySemaphore = 
                    new SemaphoreSlim(MaxConcurrencyPerSecond,MaxConcurrencyPerSecond);
        private static readonly TimeSpan SemaphoreReleaseDelay=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        public WeatherApiWithConcurrencyAdapter(WeatherForecastApi weatherForecastApi)
        {
            _weatherForecastApi = weatherForecastApi;
        }
        
        public async Task<WeatherForecastResult> GetWeatherForeCastAsync(WeatherForecastQuery query)
        {
            //Enforce concurrency
            await ConcurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync();
            
            WeatherForecastResult result;
            try
            {
                //Call Weather forecast API
                result = _weatherForecastApi.GetForecast(query);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Fire and forget :
                //the semaphore used for this call will be released after 1 second
                Task.Delay(SemaphoreReleaseDelay)
                    .ContinueWith(_ => ConcurrencySemaphore.Release())
                    .GetAwaiter();
            }

            return result;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You've only got one instance of SemaphoreSlim there, is that right?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes that is the intention .  regardless of how many instances of the adapter created, all callers will have to request semaphore handler from a single instance, other wise it wont't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see this line of code:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim  ConcurrencySemaphore = 
                    new SemaphoreSlim(MaxConcurrencyPerSecond,MaxConcurrencyPerSecond);
```

The `static` before the declaration,  means there is only one instance of `ConcurrencySemaphore` created.

So no matter how many concurrent clients do work, there will be no issue. The semaphore just stores references to the clients and raises/lowers a count bounded by the Max. No matter the number of concurrent clients, the semaphore object remains the same in terms of performance.

The `ConcurrencySemaphore` will not have an issue with the number of concurrent threads it allows to run at any given time.

You might have serious delays though in the following case:

1. Consider that your contested code requires a lot of time to execute and resources
2. If running more in parallel makes each of the requests slower then it will take more time to release for the next one
3. This might create a livelock situation for the clients that want to use your service.

What might make it even worse is this:

> If multiple threads are blocked, there is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, that controls when threads enter the semaphore.

Which might mean that high waiting times might lead some requests to wait almost indefinitely.